# Excel VBA: How to avoid code duplication - similar Properties

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have `Class` with bunch of `Properties which looks almost the same.`

```vb
  If Not gXXXReady Then 'Check global boolean variable gXXXReady
    call Object.SubProcedureYYY()
  End If
  set XXX = gXXX ' Use global variable as property value
End Property
```

What is differnet between these `Properties` is `XXX` and ``YYY`

Is there some way how to simplify this code? Something like:

```
Private Function UniversalGetFunc(ByVal VarName As String, ByVal MethodName As String)
  If Not GetVarByName(VarName) Then
    call Object.CallProcedureByName("SubProcedure" & MethodName)
  End If
End Function
...
' Usage
Property Get XXX() As Collection
  UniversalGetFunc("XXX", "YYY")
  set XXX = gXXX
End Property
```

Where `GetVarByName` and `CallProcedureByName` are (obviously) fictitious functions. `Object` is same for all my Properties, so is not neccesary to pass it to `UniversalGetFunc`.

It is even possible with (Office VBA?)

Thank you!

PS: The

Comment: If you already have a global variable (`gXXX`), why do you need to set it to a property? Or do you mean it's global to the class, but not public outside the class (a `Private` global) ?

Comment: Exactly. The global variable is private and read by `Property Get` (=read-only).